# Blazor WASM with EF Core: Where to put data model code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

When using Blazor WebAssembly, be default, three projects are created - Client, Server and Shared.
Which project is the best choice for code which defines EF Core data model?

- If I put it in Server, I have to create it's client counterpart in the Client project, which creates redundant code
- If I put it in Shared and use [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-data-annotations-to-configure-a-model), the client becomes transitively dependent on EF Core
- If I put it in Shared and use [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-fluent-api-to-configure-a-model), I'll have to check multiple files to understand even a single property (e.g. is this property required? what is it's max length?)

It seems like I'm picking the lesser of three evils, which seems to be the Fluent API.
**Are there any other aspects that I didn't consider?**

Comment: In reality not all your data models you will want to share. In that case your going to have models in two different locations. Whilst it seems attractive to use the shared folder for data models I find it only useful for POC's. Data Annotations are limited. To access the model builder in the shared dll will lead to bloat for your client.

Comment: Do you really want your database design in a DLL that is delivered to the client?

Comment: @BrianParker I'm new to Blazor and had this thought about my database design. What would be the best way to go about this, make duplicate dto's with the naming different and map in the controller or service?

Comment: @cjadd7 Have a look at "The Standard". This is a good guide to enterprise level applications this topic is covered. In particular how we setup the "Models" folder. https://github.com/hassanhabib/The-Standard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use attributes from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace on the entities in the Shared project.  These are useful in the UI and for client-side validation and will not introduce a dependency on EF.

Then use the fluent API in the Server project for any additional EF configuration.

Comment: Unless your app is tiny and meant not to grow you should use DTOs.

Answer (score 8):

You put DTOs (Data Tranfer Objects) in the Shared project. That is one of the key benefits of Blazor.

You can use your Model Entities as DTOs but I would only consider that for (very) small projects. And then EF (DbContext and Fluent API) is still only needed on the Server. Don't add it to the Shared project.

For larger projects, use separate DTOs and do the mapping in the Server APIs.